# How to fit many HTML child elements inside a parent element?

Tags: html, css

How can I fit the 2 child elements (blue border) to fit perfectly within the parent (black border) without having to adjust the height?

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxcNG.png)

My code:

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
        .parent {
            border: 3px solid black;
            height: 500px;
            
        }
        .child {
            border: 3px solid blue;
            height: 50%;
            margin: 2% 1%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**you could just use `display: flex` and `flex-direction` and set it like this :**

```css
.parent {
    border: 3px solid black;
    height: 500px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.child {
  border: 3px solid blue;
  height: 50%;
  margin: 2% 1%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
 </div>
```

[reference](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-direction/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use flexbox in this case for parent element, and then set `flex: 1` for `.child` element by removing height preliminary.

Look at example which I prepared for you. Please give me feedback, is it correct results or not, I would discuss with you problem.

https://codepen.io/codeviking/pen/QWjxVMX

Comment: Yes, this works too. Thank you.